# How to handle root JSON arrays with AlamofireObjectMapper?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, objectmapper

I'm currently using AlamofireObjectMapper to create JSON objects. I'm having a tough time accessing JSON arrays:

This is the JSON Array:

```
[
  {
    "city": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "county": "string",
  }
]
```

This is the function:

```
func getMemberDetails ( id: String) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "\(baseURL)/api/Members/\(id)/memberDetails").responseArray { (response: Response<[MemberDetailInfo], NSError>) in

      let memberDetailArray = response.result.value

      if let memberDetailArray = memberDetailArray {
        for memberDetail in memberDetailArray {
          print(memberDetail.createDate)
          print(memberDetail.id)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This Is the class:

```
class MemberDetailInfo: Mappable{

  var city: String?
  var country: String?
  var county: String?

required init?(_ map: Map) {
    mapping(map)
  }

unc mapping(map: Map) {

    city <- map["city"]
    country <- map["country"]
    county <- map["county"]
 }  
}
```

Whenever I step through it it just jumps right to the end, I’m not sure why it isn’t working.  If anyone knows how to extract the JSON data from the array it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the JSON.  It's an array of length 1 where the single element is a dictionary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this class, but you are calling mapping in your init method, whereas the docs for that extension show the method as being blank.

Comment: Your code seems to be working ok for me with one small difference.  As @Gargoyle pointed out, your init method isn't empty where mine is.

Comment: so should the init method be empty?

Comment: I found out what the issue was, the api I was trying to reached needed a header.  Once I added that it worked.

Comment: Hi, @SwiftyJD I need help , so could you please put code for Response<[MemberDetailInfo], NSError> for me it is asking for DataResponse<[T]>

Comment: @MikeAlter the code has changed since this posting, it sounds like they are asking you for a response object.  This is what it looks like:

Comment: .responseObject { (response: DataResponse<ApiResponse<MemberInfo>>) in
                    if let apiResponse = response.result.value, let memberInfo = apiResponse.data {
                        completion(memberInfo)
                    } else {
                        completion(nil)
                    }
            }